# Menu Navigation bars

Tags: html, css, web, menu, navigation

Would there be any way of making the bars under the words automatically size out to the width of the word it's under with out me having to upload specific sized bars for ever menu item I make? Thanks

[image]

Comment: If you have some of your code we can help you. **[Upload it here](http://jsfiddle.net)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it could just be a border-bottom of a link. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWsmE/1).

```
<a href="#">Portfolio</a>
<a href="#">Blog</a>
```

And

```
#footer a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use borders:

```
.menu a { 
   /* additional styling... */
   border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use background images positioned at the bottom of each menu item.

```
.menu a{
background:url(path/to/image.jpg) repeat-x bottom;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but as I said before. I'd want them kind of matching the length of the word and I don't want to have to export two of those rectangles for every word.

Comment: This is what is gonna do. It matches the length of words in each menu item. That's why you call .menu a